# Return instance of inner class in nested classes

Tags: java, scala

Here is the code:

```
import scala.collection.mutable

/**
 * Created by IDEA on 25/10/15.
 */
class HttpRequest(builder: Builder) {
  val headers: Map[String, String]
  var body: String
  var path: String

  class Builder {innerBuilder =>
    private val headers = new mutable.HashMap[String, String]()
    private var body: String = _
    private var path: String = _

    def addHeader(name: String, value: String): Unit = {
      headers.put(name, value)
      innerBuilder
    }

    def body(b: String): Builder = {
      body = b
      innerBuilder
    }

    def path(p: String) = {
      path = p
      innerBuilder
    }

    def build: HttpRequest = {
      new HttpRequest(innerBuilder)
    }
  }
}
```

I got two errors:

```
Error:(27, 7) overloaded method path needs result type
      path = p
      ^
Error:(32, 23) type mismatch;
 found   : HttpRequest.this.Builder
 required: Builder
      new HttpRequest(innerBuilder)
                      ^
```

What did I do wrong?

BTW, I was trying to translate this java file into scala:

```
/***
 * Excerpted from "Functional Programming Patterns",
 * published by The Pragmatic Bookshelf.
 * Copyrights apply to this code. It may not be used to create training material, 
 * courses, books, articles, and the like. Contact us if you are in doubt.
 * We make no guarantees that this code is fit for any purpose. 
 * Visit http://www.pragmaticprogrammer.com/titles/mbfpp for more book information.
***/
package com.mblinn.oo.tinyweb;

import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class HttpRequest {
    private Map<String, String> headers;
    private String body;
    private String path;

    public Map<String, String> getHeaders() {
        return headers;
    }

    public String getBody() {
        return body;
    }

    public String getPath() {
        return path;
    }

    private HttpRequest(Builder builder) {
        this.headers = Collections.unmodifiableMap(builder.headers);
        this.body = builder.body;
        this.path = builder.path;
    }

    public static class Builder {
        private Map<String, String> headers;
        private String body;
        private String path;

        private Builder() {
            headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
        }

        public Builder addHeader(String name, String value) {
            headers.put(name, value);
            return this;
        }

        public Builder body(String body) {
            this.body = body;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder path(String path) {
            this.path = path;
            return this;
        }

        public HttpRequest build() {
            return new HttpRequest(this);
        }

        public static Builder newBuilder() {
            return new Builder();
        }

        public static Builder builderFrom(HttpRequest request) {
            Builder builder = new Builder();
            builder.path(request.getPath());
            builder.body(request.getBody());

            Map<String, String> headers = request.getHeaders();
            for (String headerName : headers.keySet())
                builder.addHeader(headerName, 
                        headers.get(headerName));

            return builder;
        }
    }
}
```

---

### Update 1

```
import scala.collection.mutable.Map

/**
 * Created by IDEA on 25/10/15.
 */
class HttpRequest(builder: Builder) {
  val headers: Map[String, String] = Map.empty
  var body: String = _
  var path: String = _

  import scala.collection.mutable

  class Builder {
    private val headers = new mutable.HashMap[String, String]()
    private var body: String = _
    private var path: String = _

    def addHeader(name: String, value: String): this.type = {
      headers.put(name, value)
      this
    }

    def body(b: String): this.type = {
      body = b
      this
    }

    def path(p: String): this.type = {
      path = p
      this
    }

//    def build: HttpRequest = {
//      new HttpRequest(this)
//    }
  }
}
```

Still have two problems:

1. It seems refering the inner class in the construct of the outer class is not allowed (intellij cannot resolve it)
2. `new HttpRequest(this)` reports type mismatch.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with both the remaining points you mention is that `Builder` is an inner class of `HttpRequest` (in fact, as written, it is a separately-defined inner class for each specific instance of `HttpRequest`!), so needs to be addressed that way, as type `HttpRequest.Builder`. But to properly make this work, you want to move the definition of Builder into `HttpRequest`'s companion object. Something like:

```
case class HttpRequest(headers: Map[String, String], body: String, path: String)

object HttpRequest {

  def apply(builder: HttpRequest.Builder): HttpRequest = 
      HttpRequest(Map(builder.headers.toSeq: _*),
                  builder.body,
                  builder.path)

  class Builder {
    private[HttpRequest] val headers = new mutable.HashMap[String, String]()
    private[HttpRequest] var body: String = _
    private[HttpRequest] var path: String = _

    def addHeader(name: String, value: String): Builder = {
      headers.put(name, value)
      this
    }

    def body(b: String): Builder = {
      body = b
      this
    }

    def path(p: String): Builder = {
      this.path = p
      this
    }

    def build: HttpRequest = {
      HttpRequest(this)
    }
  }

  def builderFrom(request: HttpRequest): Builder = {
    val builder = new Builder().path(request.path).body(request.body)

    request.headers.foldLeft(builder){ (b,h) => b.addHeader(h._1, h._2) }
  }
}
```

A few notes here:

- I made HttpRequest a case class, as better suits a Scala data class
- the `Builder` class is now in the companion object (which can be loosely thought of as a holder for everything that in Java would be marked as "static", although it does more than that, particularly for case classes).
- The companion object is also the place to put the `buildFrom` method, which constructs the `Builder` through a combination of chained method calls and a fold over the request's headers. Because the fold produces a `Builder` as its result, this will be the return value for the `buildFrom` method, as desired.
- The `private[HttpRequest]` access modifiers on the `Builder` fields ensures that these fields are visible only inside the `HttpRequest` class, which includes the inner `Builder` class (needed so they can be accessed in the `apply` method).
- I only checked that the code above compiles in the console - I haven't actually put the code through its paces.